# accessing unique items from a pandas.core.series.Series dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

I have a pandas.core.series.Series called names:

```
print names

0      [{'code': '8', 'name': 'John'}, {...
1      [{'code': '1', 'name': 'Harry'},...
2      [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Pete'...
3      [{'code': '1', 'name': 'Harry'...
```

If there are only 10 codes and 10 unique names that belong to them.  How do I get output for those 10 names?  My first guess would be:

```
names.unique()
```

but I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + `list comprehension` with `DataFrame` constructor and [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in names.values.tolist()])
un = df['name'].unique()
print (un)
```

Another solution with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) + [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) + [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
un = np.unique(np.concatenate(names.apply(lambda x: [y['name'] for y in x])))
print (un)
```